# Golang Http Server Disable Keep-Alive

Tags: http, go, keep-alive

I trying to disable Keep-Alive Connection in golang but there is no clear explanation about how to do it..

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "fmt"
)

func helloworld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
}


func main() {

    router := httprouter.New()

    router.GET("/", helloworld)


    fmt.Println("Running :-)")

    http.Server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3030", router))
}
```

can anybody solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SetKeepAlivesEnabled is an instance configuration, not a global one.
If you really need to achieve that, instantiate your own server:

```
server := &http.Server{Addr: ":3030", Handler: router}

server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)

server.ListenAndServe()
```

Comment: Thanks. This was much  simpler to understand for peoples new to go.